# Stop RegisterAssemblyModules re-scanning an assembly if it has already been scanned?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

My situation:

I need to tell the Autofac builder to load up a referenced assembly. It hasn't been loaded on its own by this time and I need it before the bootloader finishes configuring the container.

```
public class AppRegisterModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof (IPluginManager).Assembly);
    }
}
```

This all works and the PluginManagerRegistrationModule is loaded up perfectly fine.

My concern now is I have no way to know if I've already asked the builder to load that assembly. i.e. my framework is many assemblies with their own registration modules on what they are dependent on. I can also see that cross dependency would create a cyclic loop (although I don't have cross dependencies).

Currently, I can see that doing:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof (IPluginManager).Assembly);
 builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof (IPluginManager).Assembly);
```

... does run the Registration Modules twice and I do get duplicates of registrations, and duplicates of resolved types (IEnumerable<>).

Any way to avoid the duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution has been to preload all modules and assemblies before getting to

```
containerBuilder
   .RegisterAssemblyModules(
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

with

```
private void PreConfigureRegistrationModules()
{
    var parsedAssemblies = new List<Assembly>()
    {
        typeof (Autofac.Core.IModule).Assembly
    };

    do
    {
        var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

        var unparsed = loadedAssemblies
            .Where(x => parsedAssemblies.Contains(x) == false)
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof (Autofac.Core.IModule).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .Where(x => x.IsInterface == false)
            .Where(x => x.IsAbstract == false)
            .ToList();

        var unparsedAssemblies = unparsed
            .Select(x => x.Assembly)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        if (unparsed.Count == 0)
            return;

        unparsed.ForEach(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x));

        parsedAssemblies.AddRange(unparsedAssemblies);

    } while (true);
}
```

Then in any Registration Module that needs to preload reference assemblies before the RegisterAssemblyModules I add something to force the assembly to load

```
public class AppRegisterModule : Autofac.Module
{
    static AppRegisterModule()
    {
        if (typeof (IPluginManager).Assembly == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Doesn't directly answer the duplication occurring if you scan an assembly twice, but its my work around.